# Nothing gets focused when Electron window is set to frame: false

Tags: javascript, html, electron

I know the title isn’t a proper question but.. I am having this issue where, whenever I set `frame: false` when creating a new window none of my html elements work, for example, I cannot click a button or type in a text field, it almost feels like its under some click-proof layer, and the mouse cursor is always the same, I tried `onclick=“this.select()”` and `onclick=“this.focus()”` but none of them work.

Everything is fine if I don’t remove the title bar, which kinda ruins my modern design. Operating on Windows 10

Comment: I have tested it in my electron app and everything works as expected. Take a look at **Layers** panel of the Chrome Dev Tools, it might help.

Comment: sorry for a late reply, but the layers tab is useless to me. I tried playing around with it, but its either a blank window, or my page on it, that's it I can't do anything with it, I also tried using the z-index in my css but whatever I do, nothing works.